# Change the style of the selected ng-repeat item and remove the other item's style

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm a freshman to AngularJS. I try to modify the item's style using AngularJS, but I meet this bug:
when I select another item, the background of the first item is still blue. How to change my code to fix this?
Here is my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BAoyRUNF8MnmghXH0dym?p=preview).
And here is the code.

```
<div ng-init="selectedNode = false">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="selectedNode=true" ng-class="{selected: selectedNode == true}">{{item.value}}</div>
</div>
```

When I click on 2 after click on 1, the background color of 1 should be removed. It means only one item should be selected. How to slove this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is subtle -- `ng-repeat` creates a new isolated scope for each of its entries.  So when your click handler sets `selectNode` to true, it happens on its own scope, and not its parent.

Easily remedied.  (I surrounded your example with some mock data -- I'm sure you have your own):

```
<div ng-app ng-init="items = [{value: 'red'},
   {value: 'green'},{value: 'blue'},{value: 'yellow'},
   {value: 'orange'}]">

<div ng-init="selection = { selectedNode:  null }">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" 
    ng-click="selection.selectedNode = item" 
    ng-class="{selected: selection.selectedNode == item}">
        {{item.value}}
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kfnkn827/

First, I create an object in the parent scope that can be modified by the children.  Notice that instead of a boolean, I just use a reference in the parent.  This relieves you from storing a bunch of flags.

Edit: I saw your Plinkr after submitting.  Sorry!  :-P

Comment: How to set initially first one is in bold.

Comment: @WhiteMarcus give the container element a class and then use css to pick out the first element. `<div class="container">` would allow you css that looks like `.container:first-child { font-weight: bold; }`.  If you want, you can also assign a class with `ng-class`: `ng-class="{bolded: $index == 0}"`, but you'll still need css.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things. Don't use `ng-init` to init the variable, do it in a controller. Second, `ng-repeat` creates a child scope, so you should make a data model for this, so `data.selectedNode`. Then just set the `selectedNode` to the currently repeated item, and then style it if the `selectedNode` equals the current `item`.

```
<div ng-init="data.selectedNode ={}"> <!-- do this in a controller, not ng-init -->
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="data.selectedNode=item" ng-class="{selected: data.selectedNode == item}">{{item.value}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whoops... small mistake.  You'll need to change ng-click to equal "data.selectedNode=item" and the equality to refer to the same, otherwise you are just modifying the value in the child scope.

Answer (score 0):

Please try out bellow code.
if click on row, bind clicked item value in selectedNode variable and apply  ***active-row*** class.

```
<style>
.active-row{
        background-color: #D4D0D0;
}
</style>

<div ng-init="selectedNode = false">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="selectedNode=item.value" ng-class="(selectedNode == item.value) ? 'active-row' : ''">{{item.value}}</div>
<br />
</div>
```